# Can you see the images pushed/stored in Heroku registry?

Tags: docker, heroku, deployment

I have a Gitlab pipeline that pushes my docker image to registry.heroku. Then, i am supposed to do heroku container:release -a  web and my application is correctly deployed. Can I reach and see the images in the heroku registry? I would like to have viusal access - is this possible?

Comment: I've got the same questions, did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Not that I remember, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no point in such functionality, because you have only limited amount of process types for app, which you must specify in docker image name: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#pushing-an-existing-image. Probably they also discard the image's tag (any version).